# Playing sound effect in IE6 html

Tags: html

The below coding is how I play a sound effect on my website in Firefox, Chrome and IE9:

```
<body>
<audio id="audio1">
<source src="audio.wav" type="audio/wav">
<source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
audio tag not supported.
</audio>
</body>
```

But when I test on IE6, 'audio tag not support' showed.

What I want is for my website to play the sound on IE6 and IE9. How do we embedded a sound effect in IE6?

Comment: [IE6? In 2013?](http://www.ie6countdown.com)

Comment: Haha... Yup. I still have some old pc..

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I play sound on my site. Check it out - http://code.google.com/p/jbeep/

> Play wav sounds (or beeps) in javascript, supports all web browsers.
>   Tested in: IE6, IE9, Firefox and Opera. Works perfectly. No plugins
>   required.

Comment: Where do this src="jBeep.min.js" come from 
gmustudent?

Comment: Go to this link - http://code.google.com/p/jbeep/downloads/detail?name=jBeep.zip - Then download the file and add it to your class path. The js file is tiny which is a huge plus for designers who don't want huge piles of code on their site.

Comment: To be honest this is the easiest way and the best! The function is written by programmers at MIT and it basically validates to check which browser the user has. If they have on that supports HTML 5 do this, if safari do this, if ie6 do this etc etc. It's a bullet proof system that is less then 100 lines of code and once added to your site all you do is add a button and call the function wherever you want. If you need some help with how to add this to your site let me know but trust me I currently use this and I love it!

Comment: I already have a js file included in my coding. Are we able to include more that one js files in the coding?

Comment: All you have to do is copy the source code of the entire function, and then paste it into the js file you currently have. once it's in there you can call it.

Answer (score 0):

ie6 doesn't support audio element. you can turn that on using html5 shiv. but your best bet maybe to just use html5media lib. you can find this here: http://html5media.info/